# getting data from another table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with an item_id and some other fields.

```
item_id,name,address,postcode
```

I also have a table of messages that relate to an item_id

```
item_id,user_id,message
```

What I am trying to do is make a query that selects all rows in a specific postcode (not an issue there)

but also return something (0 or 1 for example) if the user that is logged in also has messages associated with the item

so I have a basic query like this:

```
select item_id,name,address,postcode from items where postcode in ('3000')
```

but I want to incorporate the messages table somehow so that I am left with a flag to show that the user_id has or has not sent a message related to the item

How can I do this?

I tried a left join, but that will only show results where the user has messages, whereas I want the result regardless of if the user actually sent a message, I just want to know if they did or not.

Comment: Sidenote: Why are you using `IN()` for one value?

Comment: because the actual query may contain multiple values for postcode

Comment: Ok, that part I didn't know ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use an `IF` condition to check the `message` field
`IF(message.message <>'', 1, 0) as flag`

```
SELECT 
    items.item_id,name,address,postcode, 
    IF(message.message <>'', 1, 0) as flag, message 
FROM items 
LEFT JOIN message ON items.item_id = message.item_id 
WHERE postcode in ('3000')
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: While this wasn't exactly the solution, it got me going down the right track to work it out